# AEM dialog tab replication

Tags: dialog, aem

I am working on aem tool. My requirement is to create a dialog with a single tab. I need to write a listener in such a way that by clicking on a "ADD +" button, I could replicate similiar kind of tab as tab 2 in the same dialog. Kindly help me with this. 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you using Classic UI or Touch UI? What is it that you need to achieve? Maybe there's an easier way than to clone a tab.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you need a [multifield](http://blogs.adobe.com/sunil/2013/11/04/developing-a-multifield-widget-for-a-cq-component/) component.